# How to update powershell .PSD1 file

Tags: powershell

The content of the .psd1 file is

```
@{   

Oracle_Backup_Completed = 'N'
Oracle_Load_Completed = 'N'

}
```

After certain process, I want to update `Oracle_Load_Completed = 'Y'`.

Can you please help how I can do this?

Comment: the content of .psd1 is not posted correctly.
@ {
Oracle_Backup_Completed = 'N' 
Oracle_Load_Completed = 'N'
}